# Multi Interface resolver by using any Design Pattern in java

Tags: java

I have created two Interfaces. Each interface extends one other interface. I have created one method in a Factory class and I am creating the object of each interface object by using implemented class in each case. But problem is that how we manage multiple return type in 
one method. I know this is not possible because method always return one value at a time. But I want dynamic return type I don't want to use Object type. is there any solution for this problem.

One more thing when that return dynamic object then the method of that object should be call without typecasting.

```
@Service
public class ModuleResolverFactory {


    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    public Object getModule(String objectType) throws VEnableBusinessException {
        switch (objectType) {
            case Constant.API_TYPE_DEE:
                return context.getBean(SceModuleService.class);
            case Constant.API_TYPE_SCE:
                return context.getBean(SceModuleService.class);
            default:
                throw new VEnableBusinessException(Constant.STATUS_FAILURE, MessageSupplier.EXCEPTION_MESSAGE.get(),"Invalid objectType found: " + objectType);

        }
    }
}








 public Object add(RequestDto requestDto) throws VEnableBusinessException {

        Object res=null;

        logModel.getExecutionSteps().add("Starting Executing Request For ADD Apis : " + requestDto);

        Object module=moduleResolverFactory.getModule(requestDto.getObjectType());

        logModel.getExecutionSteps().add("Fetched Module For : " + UtilFunctions.orgAppMessage.apply(requestDto.getClientId(), requestDto.getProjectId(), requestDto.getEnvironment()));

        res = ((DeeModuleService)(module)).add(requestDto);

        logModel.getExecutionSteps().add("Api Added : " + requestDto);

        return res;
    }
```

In the above code I am casting the object but I don't want this I want dynamic because in future It may 100 types

Comment: Are you saying that you have interface `DeeModuleService` (!!!) and `SceModuleService` that both extend `ModuleService`?

Comment: interface DeeModuleService extends ModuleResolverIsp   !!! and  interface SceModuleService extends ModuleResolver   !!!------ both interface is extending the different interface and each interface different methods and ModuleResolverIsp is also child interface of ModuleResolver. Today I have only two interfaces but it will be more.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the best way to do this kind of things is by passing the interface as an argument:

```
@Service
public class ModuleResolverFactory {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    public <T> T getModule(Class<T> objectType) {
        return context.getBean(objectType);
    }
}
```

Comment: But when we use generic then at the end you have to specify the type when we call getModule() method otherwise it will return Object type.

Comment: @NiteshSharma yes

Comment: Is there any design pattern available for it ?

Comment: @NiteshSharma not sure

Answer (score -1):

May be your two top level interfaces can be made to extend a common parent interface. The parent interface can then declare the method 'add(requestDto)'

You can then return the ParentInterface in your factory method.

Comment: That is fine when parent interface is there then no problem. but  there is no parent interface because Every module has there own interface and own methods. If I create a parent Interface then It will not be good because Every module has there own methods and I don't want to use 1st module interface methods to other module interface because when I will implement them then unnecessary method will be override.

Comment: @NiteshSharma You can have empty parent interface like `interface A {}`, which does not have any methods but just as a marking.

Comment: You can also use reflection if the add(requestDto) exists in all objects. o.getClass().getMethod("addDto").invoke(o);

Comment: Suppose I have two interfaces each interface has there own methods that both interfaces extending one interface also. So how I can make a parent interface of that both interfaces